# Android Studio illegible/unreadable special characters in linux

Tags: android, linux, archlinux

As the picture shows Android Studio has illegible special characters.

I use UTF-8 (/etc/locale.conf)

> LANG=en_US.UTF-8

What might be the cause of the problem?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9nzqlc07wpah9bo/2014-06-15-202014_1280x800_scrot.png

Comment: We can't see the screenshot.  Please post it as an Image in the body of the post itself.

Comment: Apparently i solved by forcing android-studio to use SystemAAFont(Default) simply run :          
**_JAVA_OPTIONS: '-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSetting=on' android-studio**

Comment: Cool.  You might want to post that as an answer and accept your own answer, to make it more visible that this has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i solved by forcing android-studio to use SystemAAFont(Default) simply run : _JAVA_OPTIONS: '-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSetting=on' android-studio